# Formtastic bootstrap checkbox label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I've got phone_numbers which have 3 permissions of local, regional and national - each a boolean.

My form at the moment looks like this:

```
=semantic_form_for @phone_number, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  =f.semantic_errors
  =f.inputs do
    =f.input :phone_number_type, :as => :select, :collection => PhoneNumber::PHONE_NUMBER_TYPES, :include_blank => false, :label => "Type", :required => false
    =f.input :phone_number, :required => false
    =f.semantic_fields_for :permission do |permission_fields|
      =permission_fields.input :local, :label => false
      =permission_fields.input :regional, :label => false
      =permission_fields.input :national, :label => false

  =f.actions do
    =f.action :submit, :label => "Save"
```

Putting label false give each checkbox a single label to the right.  Without it each checkbox has 2 labels - one on the left and one on the right.  I've floated the 3 checkboxes, so they are in a horizonal line, so I'd really like local to have a label that says "Permissions" on the left and "local" on the right.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up hiding them with css